# How to make tinymce work with iframe?

Tags: tinymce

When I input `<iframe>` with its **HTML Source Editor**, it's just filtered.

Is there an option to make it work with `<iframe>`?

Comment: Mind giving more details? Is this a bare TinyMCE setup or a plugin for some kind of CMS? What config have you initialized it with? Which version of TinyMCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this:

You should read in the documentation about valid elements.
You have to add valid elements in your **tinymce init**, otherwise tinymce will delete those elements:

Add:

```
extended_valid_elements : "iframe[src|width|height|name|align]",
```