# tinymce doesn't obey extend_valid_elements

Tags: configuration, iframe, tinymce

I'm trying to set up tinyMCE so that it would work with google maps iframe. TinyMCE cleanup procedure strips that iframe out.

So i found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748647/how-to-make-tinymce-work-with-iframe) and [there](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=7301), that says i need to insert an `extend_valid_elements : "iframe",` into tinyMCE.init.

But anyway, it will strip out my iframe. I tried adding `iframe` or `iframe[*]` or `iframe[src|width|height|name|align]`, but it will not work. If i, however, change `cleanup = false`, then it doesn't strip out iframe. But i'd rather do it the right way.

My

```
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode : "textareas",
        editor_selector : "rte",
        convert_urls : false,
        content_css : "<?php echo $html->url("/css/rte.css") ?>",
        plugins : "table, paste, xhtmlxtras, safari",
        file_browser_callback : "tinyBrowser",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright, justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,sub,sup,link,unlink,image,pastetext, pasteword, selectall, forecolor, backcolor,acronym,del,formatselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "tablecontrols,cleanup,removeformat,code",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        theme_advanced_resizing : false,
        handle_event_callback: function CleanupHTML_callback(e)
        {
                if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 86 && e.type != "keyup")
                {
                        setTimeout('tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand("'+e.target.editorId+'", "mceCleanup", true)',1);
                        //return false;
                }
                return true;
        },
        force_p_newlines : false,
        force_br_newlines : true,
        convert_newlines_to_brs : false,
        remove_linebreaks : false,
        cleanup_on_startup : false,
        extend_valid_elements : "iframe[src|width|height|name|align]",
        //invalid_elements : "script,onclick,ondblclick,onkeydown,onkeypress,onkeyup,onmousedown,onmousemove,onmouseout,onmouseover,onmouseup,font",
        height: "500"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the configuration parameter correctly using the correct name [extended_valid_elements](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aextended_valid_elements), not extend_valid_elements.

Comment: glad to have been able to help